# Using polyval and polyfit to plot linear regression on semi-log charts

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib + numpy to generate linear regressions using the polyfit and polyval functions

```
lateReg = np.polyfit(x=xm,y=mcherryp,deg=1)
ax1.plot(xm, np.polyval(lateReg,xm), 'r-')
earlyReg = np.polyfit(xv,venusp,deg=1)
ax1.plot(xv, np.polyval(earlyReg,xv), 'g-')
```

However, since my x axis is log, the lines don't look very linear. [This site](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/curve-fitting/index.htm?reg_fitting_lines_to_semilog.htm) says I can 
simply use `y=m*log(x)+b` and my line will be linear again, but I'm unsure of how to do so with the code I have (and I'd like to use these functions instead of doing it manually). Any ideas? Is it as simple as:

```
ax1.plot(log(xm), np.polyval(lateReg,xm), 'r-')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your data looks like a straight line on the semilog plot, you want

```
p = np.polyfit(np.log(xm), mcherryp, 1)
ax1.semilogx(xm, p[0] * np.log(xm) + p[1], 'r-')
```

In this case, and the loglog case, I usually think that `polyval` is not useful.